# When is the request fired? http.request()

Tags: node.js

A little question concerning node's `http.request(options, callback)` method.
I got the following example code from the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback):

```
var options = {
  hostname: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/upload',
  method: 'POST'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

**Question:**
When is the actual HTTP request getting fired?

Is it at the time of assigning the request to the `req` variable (line 8), or maybe at `req.end()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The explanation is right in the documentation following the example:

> Note that in the example `req.end()` was called. With `http.request()` one must always call req.end() to signify that you're done with the request - even if there is no data being written to the request body.

The call of `req.end()` is mandatory. Note that `req` is a `http.ClientRequest`. The documentation of [`http.ClientRequest.prototype.end`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_end_data_encoding) gives you the final clue:

> `request.end([data], [encoding])`
>   Finishes sending the request